# logstash output to elasticsearch with document_id; what to do when I don't have a document_id?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration

I have some logstash input where I use the `document_id` to remove duplicates. However, most input doesn't have a `document_id`. The following plumbs the actual `document_id` through, but if it doesn't exist, it gets accepted as literally `%{document_id}`, which means most documents are seen as a duplicate of each other. Here's what my output block looks like:

```
output {
        elasticsearch_http {
            host => "127.0.0.1"
            document_id => "%{document_id}"
        }
}
```

I thought I might be able to use a conditional in the output. It fails, and the error is given below the code.

```
output {
        elasticsearch_http {
            host => "127.0.0.1"
            if document_id {
                document_id => "%{document_id}"
            } 
        }
}

Error: Expected one of #, => at line 101, column 8 (byte 3103) after output {
        elasticsearch_http {
    host => "127.0.0.1"
    if
```

I tried a few "if" statements and they all fail, which is why I assume the problem is having a conditional of any sort in that block. Here are the alternatives I tried:

```
if document_id <> "" {
if [document_id] <> "" {
if [document_id] {
if "hello" <> "" {
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're close with the conditional idea but you can't place it inside a plugin block. Do this instead:

```
output {
  if [document_id] {
    elasticsearch_http {
      host => "127.0.0.1"
      document_id => "%{document_id}"
    } 
  } else {
    elasticsearch_http {
      host => "127.0.0.1"
    } 
  }
}
```

(But the suggestion in one of the other answers to use the uuid filter is good too.)

Comment: perfect. As I said to Val I prefer this in case the uuid accidentally gets omitted.

Answer (score 5):

One way to solve this is to make sure a `document_id`is always available. You can achieve this by adding a [UUID filter](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-uuid.html) in the filter section that would create the `document_id` field if it is not present.

```
filter {
    if "" in [document_id] {
        uuid {
            target => "document_id"
        }
    }
}
```

**Edited per Magnus Bäck's suggestion. Thanks!**

Comment: The typical way to check for the existence of a field would be `if [document_id] { ... }`.

Comment: Val, this is a great answer and probably the most "correct" way to do it. I'm going with Magnus's solution because it's safer if I happen to miss the uuid on a filtered input. I wish I could accept both, as they are both great answers.

Comment: Sure thing! Best is to try both approaches and see for yourself, though ;)

Comment: @Magnus-Bäck be careful with this if the field you are checking is a boolean

Answer (score 0):

Reference : [docinfo_fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-elasticsearch.html#plugins-filters-elasticsearch-docinfo_fields)

For any document added in elasticsearch, the _id is auto-generated if not specified during insert. We can use this same _id later to update/delete/search queries by using `docinfo_fields` feature.

Example :

```
filter {
    json {
        source => "message"
    }
    
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "http://localhost:9200/"
        user => elastic
        password => elastic
        query => "..."
        docinfo_fields => {
          "_id" => "docid"
          "_index" => "document_index"
        }
    }
    if ("_elasticsearch_lookup_failure" not in [tags]) {
        #... doc update logic ...
    }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "http://localhost:9200/"
        user => elastic
        password => elastic
        index => "%{document_index}"
        action => "update"
        doc_as_upsert => true
        document_id => "%{docid}"
    }
}
```